# Python HTML gui with drag and drop functionality

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I had to rewrite this question because it was too vague.

I was inspired by my own answer to [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770394/ipython-notebook-make-output-cells-like-markdown/17874834#17874834) and began to think that it might be easier and more cross platform to make a GUI by HTML rather than libraries such as Tkinter.

I want to hear what kind of experience and modules you stackoverflow users have and vote the best (easiest) solution as my answer (and vote the other good ones up).

I imagine some fictive code like this:

```
import someMagicHTML5Module as html5 # it does not need to be HTML5
import someBrowserModule as browser
from time import sleep

listOfChoices = ['Item '+ str(x+1) for x in range(6)]

listHandle = html5().createList()
for option in listOfChoices:
    listHandle.addListItem(option)

buttonHandle = html5().button("Summit")

htmlSite = html5().superGlue(listHandle, buttonHandle)

browserHandle = browser().open(htmlSite)

while  buttonHandle.hasBeenPressed() == False:
    # Waiting for the user to arrange the list and press the summit button 
    sleep(1)

listOrder = listHandle.getList()

for item in listOrder:
    print item
```

This would open a browser window like this:

[image: Mockup]

(MockUp created from [this site](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/))

Comment: I guess the full answer would be - no, it is not crazy. You've described precisely what you want, but what is your problem in getting it done?

Comment: I'm asking if it can be done and what experience other have had with a similar thing. Sometimes people know awesome modules that don't just pop up in a google search.

Comment: @MartijnPieters would you mind removing the `on hold` from my question?

Comment: I alone cannot do that. Since you edited your question, it is automatically added to the reopen review queue, and the community will vote on whether or not to reopen in due course.

Comment: @tuergeist would you consider voting for an reopening of my question?

Comment: @Codie would you mind voting for a reopening of my question?

Comment: @morgano would you consider voting for an reopening of my question?

Comment: @user568109 would you mind voting for a reopening of my question?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. I have done this using JavaScript (server was on Google App Engine (Python)). JavaScript code will drag and drop the list that your Python will load. After you close your list you should just save the order in which you placed your items. (If you need I can send you example of the code that I had)

Example of this would be task panel in Gmail.

Or you can check [simmilar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361779/drag-and-drop-to-reorder-html-lists)

Comment: I don't have much experience with JavaScript and Python, but would very much like to learn how.